# How to enable rebuild option for a build triggered by Gerrit

Tags: jenkins-plugins, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I have a Jenkins build, triggered by Gerrit. I have the "Retrigger" option only. I want to have the "Rebuild" option as in plain builds.

Jenkins ver. 2.150.1, Gerrit Trigger 2.27.7, Rebuilder 1.29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Rebuild" option will automatically appears in builds executed using the build button. If the build was trigged by Gerrit you can't "rebuild" it but, at the end, the "retrigger" option will do the same effect.

Comment: It's not the same effect, because Rebuild allows to change the parameters, while Retrigger does not (as in Replay).